# Solid cedar acoustic - is damage near sound hole of concern?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, repair

I am considering buying a particular solid cedar top acoustic, but it has some damage near the sound hole (Otherwise, I don't think there is any concern I have).

[image: damage near sound hole]

Is that too much damage (particularly becaute it almost spans a section from the sound hole to the edge) ?

Should I repair it or get it repaired (or not worry), and if so, how should it be repaired ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the damage is as shallow as the picture suggests, don't worry.  If it's deeper than it looks, maybe worry.  Take it to a guitar technician.

Answer (score 1):

That looks superficial. It most likely won't make any difference to the sound or playing of the instrument. I'd leave it like it is, as it won't be cheap to have it repaired.